# YOLOv5 decreasing inference speed

Tags: yolov5

I am using YOLOv5x model on my custom dataset. Inference time is initially 0.055s, then it increases up to 2 seconds gradually. Same thing happens in the validation too. Iterations start from 6 seconds and end as much as 34 seconds.

This performance drop happens in every training setting so I don't think it is about the dataset. I can train it without performance drop in the ssh server.

My current gpu is RTX 2070. I have 16gb ram and i7-9750h cpu.

edit:
If I split images into small parts and wait between the inferences, I get optimal performance. Also, If I run detect for the same part without waiting, I get worse inference time for the same images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the thermal throttling. Cleaning and new thermal paste solved  the problem. You can also see the original answer from the [GitHub page.](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8736)